# Good Tiff library for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, tiff

I know [libtiff](http://www.libtiff.org/libtiff.html) for C, but haven't found a port for .NET. Does such a port exist?

Answer (score 26):

My company recently released a free and open-source(New BSD license) version of LibTiff written using only managed C# (license permits commercial use and distribution).

https://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/

Comment: What about retrieving the specific page from tiff document? Can't find an example in your documentation

Comment: @nKognito please don't use comments for asking *new* questions.

Answer (score 12):

What about using the built in .NET class? See ["How to: Encode and Decode a TIFF Image"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969817.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: There are a number of TIFF files that I've personally encountered that the built in .NET classes / GDI will choke on. Frequently a "A generic error occurred in GDI+" exception when loading multipaged TIFF files which LibTIFF will open without issue.

Comment: GDI+ is one of most unreliable solutions and poorly  developed .net class

Comment: @Dexters: agreed, because GDI+ is never .net in the first place. It was [plain old C DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533969(v=vs.85).aspx); even its C++ interface are mere wrappers.