# WPF BitmapImage and TIFF with CMYK + Alpha

Tags: wpf, tiff, alpha, bitmapimage, cmyk

I am using this code snippet to load various image files:

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage ();
bitmap.BeginInit ();
bitmap.UriSource = new System.Uri (path);
bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
bitmap.EndInit ();
```

This works fine for TIFF files stored as RGB, RGB+Alpha and CMYK. <strike>However, if I try to load a TIFF file using CMYK colors and an alpha channel, I get an exception (the file format is not recognized as being valid by the decoder).</strike>

I was previously using the [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) library and a thin C# wrapper on top of it. FreeImage 3.x has partial support for this kind of image format, i.e. I had to load the TIFF twice, once as CMYK without transparency and once as RGB+Alpha; this trick is needed since FreeImage only gives access to at most 4 simultaneous color channels.

<strike>I'd like to know if there is a supported way to load CMYK+Alpha bitmaps? Either directly in C# or by going through some interop code, but preferably without having to use a third-party DLL (other than the .NET 4 framework libraries).</strike>

An example of such a TIFF file can be found [here](http://www.opac.ch/files/cmyka.tif).

**EDIT** : I can no longer reproduce the problem, the following code works just fine:

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage ();
bitmap.BeginInit ();
bitmap.UriSource = new System.Uri (path);
bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
bitmap.EndInit ();
byte[] pixels = new byte[bitmap.PixelHeight*bitmap.PixelWidth*5];
bitmap.CopyPixels (pixels, bitmap.PixelWidth * 5, 0);
```

But I am still stuck: how can I find out that the source image was encoded as CMYK plus Alpha channel? When looking at the `Format` property, I get only the information that the image has 40 bits per pixel. All the interesting stuff is stored in the following non-public properties:

```
bitmap.Format.FormatFlags == IsCMYK | NChannelAlpha;
bitmap.Format.HasAlpha == true;
```

Is there any official way of getting to them, without resorting to reflection?

Comment: Do you have any link to a TIFF using CMYK with alpha channel where this problem occurs? I'm unable to reproduce this

Comment: I added a link to my TIFF image in the question (http://www.opac.ch/files/cmyka.tif)

Comment: Ah, you're right. Sorry, totally missed it..

Comment: It might be that I totally missunderstood this question, but cmyka.tiff loads up fine for me with the code you posted without any exception and I'm able to display it in an `Image`

Comment: @Maleak: I have just tried again and now I can load the TIFF CMYK+A image. This is really strange. Might some automatic Windows Update have fixed this without me noticing? Mabe.

Comment: I looked around in `BitmapImage` and `PixelFormat` with Reflector and I don't see any other way then to use reflection to get those values. Is it a possible bottleneck for your application?

Answer (score 0):

I can only say this because I've had the issues with some files: it might be a better way to convert the tiff to png24 first and then load it up.

Even Photoshop puts up a warning if a user tries to save a CMYK Tiff file and ticks 'Transparency': "Many programs do not support transparency in TIFF. Save transparency information?"

So converting prior to opening might be the safe way to go.

Maybe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageconverter.aspx would do it but I doubt it, you probably need some extra piping.

HTH.

Comment: Converting the image is not working (the image converter does not seem to support my CMYK+alpha channel images). And I don't want to convert to RGB first, as I really need to access all five components for every pixel (Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Black and Alpha).

Comment: @kyle: I was mistaken, the code works. I've no idea why I was previously getting an exception.

Comment: Glad to hear. Good old rebuild all.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a guess, but GDI+ might be able to load such files.

System.Drawing.Image etc.

There is an interop class which can render GDI+ images in WPF.

Comment: I have not found how to do that. From what I understand, GDI+ always returns RGB values to me and there is no way to get to the original CMYK values. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Actually I have no idea. I only used this aaproach to get images from TWAIN and dislay them in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I found another question on SO which linked to this library:

http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/

[Good Tiff library for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294391)

I hope this might help.

Comment: Thank you, but I have come from FreeImage and I do not want to go back therre; I had too many issues when memory was getting low. I observed many crashes in my application when calling FreeImage, most probably caused by memory corruption. But the libtiff.net seems an interesting alternative.