# Why are pixel values of an image different between reading methods?

Tags: c#, image, matlab, image-processing

This puzzles me for last two hours. Reading an image file results in different pixel values between imread in Matlab and Image.FromFile in C#?

```
aa=imread('myfile.tif')

max(aa(:)) = 248 in matlab
```

In C#

```
var image2Array = imageToByteArray((Bitmap) Image.FromFile("myfile.tif"));
byte maxx = 0;
foreach(var a in image2Array)
{
     maxx = Math.Max(maxx, a);
}
//maxx = 255
```

Futhermore, in Matlab,

```
aa(1,1) = 13, 
aa(1,2) = 13
```

but in C#

```
image2Array[0]=17,  
image2Array[1]=0
```

They should be the same.

BTW, in this case, pixel type is uint8. so there is no dimensional difference.

If you ask me how I got byte array from Image, I used [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to make this method.

```
    public byte[] imageToByteArray(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        // Lock the bitmap's bits.  
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
            rect,
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            bmp.PixelFormat);

        // Get the address of the first line.
        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

        // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap. 
        int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride)*bmp.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

        // Copy the RGB values into the array.
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
        // Unlock the bits.
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        return rgbValues;
    }
```

What did I do wrong here? I suspect that they use different reading algorithms because two resulting images look same.

**UPDATE:**

I don't think there is anything wrong with what I was doing. I concluded that reading tif as a bitmap was the cause of the problem. To confirm this theory,

1. I displayed the two images and they looked exactly the same. So there is no mistake on my part, I think.
2. I tried to read the same file with opencv and its pixel values were exactly the same as the ones from matlab. This was surprisingly to me. I would very cautiously use Bitmap in C# from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TIFF has many formats, you are attempting to read it as a bitmap.

I suggest reading it using a proprietary TIFF reader instead : [Good Tiff library for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294391/good-tiff-library-for-net)

Comment: Yeah I was trying to do with OpenCV. Thanks for confirming that.

Comment: I was able to replicate the image from imread in Matlab with OpenCV. So I think reading it as a bitmap is not a good idea which is surprising to me.

Answer (score 5):

Your `imageToByteArray` method *does* return a byte array, but you can't assume each byte is a pixel.  The `PixelFormat` determines how the pixel data is stored in the byte array.

The best site I've seen that documents this is [Bob Powell's lockbits page](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx).

If the PixelFormat is `Format8bppIndexed`, then this (untested) code should give you the color values for each pixel.

```
var bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("myfile.tif");

// ******* Begin copying your imageToByteArray method
// Lock the bitmap's bits.  
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
    rect,
    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
    bmp.PixelFormat);

// Get the address of the first line.
IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

// Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap. 
int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
byte[] imageData = new byte[bytes];

// Copy the RGB values into the array.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, imageData, 0, bytes);
// Unlock the bits.
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
// ******* End copying your imageToByteArray method

// Now loop through each pixel...  The byte array contains extra bytes
// used for padding so we can't just loop through every byte in the array.
// This is done by using the Stride property on bmpData.
for (int y = 0; y < bmpData.Height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bmpData.Width; x++)
    {
        var offset = (y * bmpData.Stride) + x;

        // The byte in the image array gives the offset into the palette
        var paletteIndex = imageData[offset];

        // Given the offset, find the matching color in the palette
        var color = bmp.Palette.Entries[offset];

        // Look at the color value here...
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 to this. As a quick litmus test, check the number of elements in byte array against the size of image as reported by Matlab. I'd venture to guess it's larger.

Comment: I think I understand that. But the tif file in this case is uint8 which is same as byte or unsigned char.

Comment: @peakxu I've already checked. number of elements between the two are the same.

Comment: @david, what's the value of the PixelFormat property?

Comment: @David It's PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed

Comment: The "Indexed" part means that it is using a color palette.  You'll find all of the colors under the bitmap's "Palette.Entries" property.  I haven't tested this, but my first guess is that the byte in the image data is the index into the palette array.  If you just want to know what the brightest color is, you can just look at the palette without even looking at the image's byte array.

Comment: @David I think you are half right. all the palette.entries does not appear in pixels.

Comment: @David I read your reference but I can't find anything wrong in my code. Could you?

Comment: @david, I've added some sample code that shows how to loop through each pixel and find the color.

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing. I think there is some issue with handling tif as a bitmap. I confirmed that with OpenCV. That is, I was able to replicate image that imread in matlab produced with opencv. Anyway, thanks for your effort on your answer. I appreciate it.