# How can I open a CMYK tif image and read the pixels CMYK values?

Tags: c#, tiff, cmyk

I have search around and can see many questions on converting values but I cant find a library that gives me the CMYK values, I can only see examples that get the RGB values?

If there a library that can open CMYK tif files and do this?

Comment: Have you seen this question? [Good Tiff library for .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294391/good-tiff-library-for-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [LibTiff.Net](https://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) library (disclaimer: I am one of it's developers). The library can provide access to data in TIFF without conversion of the data.

Following methods might be useful for you:

- [Tiff.ReadScanline](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/help/api/BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Tiff.html#BitMiracle_LibTiff_Classic_Tiff_ReadScanline_System_Byte___System_Int32_) (generic access to decoded but not converted samples grouped in scanlines)
- [Tiff.ReadEncodedStrip](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/help/api/BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Tiff.html#BitMiracle_LibTiff_Classic_Tiff_ReadEncodedStrip_System_Int32_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) (the same as above but for strips)
- [Tiff.ReadEncodedTile](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/help/api/BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Tiff.html#BitMiracle_LibTiff_Classic_Tiff_ReadEncodedTile_System_Int32_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) (the  same as above but for tiles)

There are also [Getting Started](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/help/articles/KB/getting-started.html) tutorial and some [samples](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples).

Comment: Hi, thanks, I was looking at this, but could not see any reference to CMYK values... will look at those methods...

Comment: I want to compare 2 tif images, which will be CMYK images, created from 2 pdf files, 1 pdf being an optimised version of the other. So I need to read each pixel, calculate the delta-E and get an average of this over the whole document. Does a Scanline take a row of pixels? and how do I read the CMY and K values? Not sure of the technical details, but is it possible to read the Lab colour in each pixel rather than the CMYK?

Comment: Any of the mentioned methods will return unpacked raster data. In case of CMYK and `ReadScanline` a buffer of `(Width * 4)` bytes will be returned. I do not remember ordering of bytes (and it might differ), but probably buffer will contain bytes in order like `c m y k c m y k ....`

Comment: so, for images of the same size you can easily calculate the difference you want by simply finding difference between bytes in corresponding positions.

Comment: LibTiff is not capable of converting anything to Lab color space. You should not have any issues to read Lab-encoded images, though. You might use the same methods to do so.